# @Conditional to detect two classes of same name and not load one?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a library and an app.  The library is meant to contain reusable @RestControllers across our team.  We have a FooController that's in the library and its is good for 90% of our uses.  Sometimes though a custom FooController is needed.  I would like to add an @Condition(FooControllerConditional.class) to our library and annotate the FooController with this conditional.  I would like the condition to prevent the library's FooController from loading if there is a FooController loaded in the application.  It's also possible for FooController to be in a different package in the library and app, this makes things harder because I can't use Class.forName...

Any suggestions?  ( I would like to do this instead of an exclude filter in component scan because those are a little unwieldy and this would be more automatic. )

Comment: Seems possible. What problem do you have?

Comment: So far I have been unable to determine how to use the matches interface to determine if I have two classes with the simple name "FooController".  `boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata)`.  It also doesn't seem possible to get a list of all the loaded classes without using a Java Agent.

Comment: Why don't you use `@Profile` annotation?

Comment: Why dose not used controller advice?

Comment: @aliakbarazizkhani how would I use ControllerAdvice to accomplish this?